# Android how to point Qibla direction on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello everyone I have to show my pointer to Qibla direction as given in attached image from my current location. I have lat/lang of Qibla and also lat/lang of my current position.
how i will do it?.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need 2 markers, one facing north, and one pointing to Qibla.

For the second marker, you can use this [marker setRotation function](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setRotation%28float%29) to rotate the marker to point to the Qibla.

Note that rotation of the marker is in degrees clockwise about the marker's anchor point, and I saw you have a counter clockwise degree listed, so be sure to convert that.